# How to display html form with multiple type of values on next page after submit using getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was creating a `form` with multiple `input` type of data like `date`, `number` and `text`. How do I display it on next page when I hit the submit button? I want to write a paragraph using these values. I was using JS.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function generatesentence(){
            var var1 = "In ";
            var var2 = document.getElementById('orgname');
            var var3 = document.getElementById('postionnumber');
            var var4 = "The city location is ";
            var var5 = document.getElementById('cityname');
            var var6 = ". The last date of application is ";
            var var7 = document.getElementById('lasdat');
            document.write(var1+var2.value+var3.value+var4+var5.value+var6+var7.value);
            }
        </script>
```

```css
body{
  background-image: url("ORGANIZATIONALRE-ORGANIZATIONOR.jpg");
}

.organization-information{
  width: 360px;
  padding:15% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
 .form{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: LightBlue ;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
 }

.form input{
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 1;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form-button{
  font-family: "roboto0",sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.concat{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: LightBlue ;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vacancies Available</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="formstyle.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="organization-information">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="Org-info-form">
      name of organization:          <input type="text" name="Name" id="orgname" placeholder="enter the name here"/><br/>
      No of positions  :             <input type="number" name id="postionnumber" placeholder="Enter number of positions avaialble"/><br/>
      City Name           :          <input type="text" id="cityname" placeholder="Enter city name here"/><br/>
      Last Date for application :    <input type="date" id="lasdat" placeholder="Last date of application"/><br/>
                                     <button onclick="generatesentence()">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far ?

Comment: In `toString(document.getElementById())`, where have you defined *toString*? The result of `document.getElementById()` will be a type error as you haven't supplied any arguments. If you're trying to stringify DOM elements, get their [*outerHTML*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).

Comment: It seems complicated and I have just started working these. Can I use String(document.getElementById()) instead of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to access the input text of the input field.
I would suggest you to use

`var2.innerText` or `var2.value`

similar to every variable you are using

```
getElementById()
```

and I believe var3 will show an Error as `getElementById()` needs an argument.

Edit: here is a modified code

```
function generatesentence(){
    var var1 = "In ";
    var var2 = document.getElementById('orgname');
    var var3 = (document.getElementById('postionnumber'));
    var var4 = "The city location is ";
    var var5 = document.getElementById('cityname');
    var var6 = ". The last date of application is ";
    var var7 = (document.getElementById('lasdat'));
    document.write(var1+var2.value+var3.value+var4+var5.value+var6+var7.value);
    }
```

Comment: Is it because I am not passing id to the function. If so how to pass them

Comment: first remove `String` for `var3` and `var7`
and then use `.value` instead of `innerText`

Comment: also you don't have to pass id to the functions

Comment: tried to run it with string() and without string(), with innerText and value both, by passing id and without passing them too. Is there nothing I can do or should try

Comment: look at here, it works  https://js.do/code/251697

what is the error it is showing, to see the error press F12 on any browser

Comment: please explain clearly what is it not working or what is the expected output and what is the output your getting

Comment: Thanks Dark_thunder it worked. It prints the statement I wanted to. Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: happy to help, select this answer as accepted answer

Comment: If I remove the css code it runs. But when I include it it doesn't. So I guess this is the error of css not the entire code. But still thank you for your valuable time. So, it helped me realize I am bad at css.

Comment: It's night here but still when I look at what I solved today with your help.... I really can't define the filling

Comment: always happy to help mate :D